# When I click back button the account is log out in java in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have 4 (four) activity in my project. Main Activity, LoginActivity, DashboardAdmin Activity and CategoryAdd Activity.

I am using login system in the LoginActivity and I am logining. After that I am adding a category with userid in my app to firebase. I able to do this but without adding category or after adding category in the CategoryAddActivity I click to back navigation button the account is logout. (normally it must go to DashboardAdminActivity but goes to MainActivity) Everytime I must login again. I want to click back button without logout.

here is the problem: after logging in, there is no problem navigating through activities.  but when I press the back button on the Add category page, it exits my account and redirects it to the login page again.  normally it should have taken me to the admin page without logging out of my account.  I have to re-login every time I press the back button after adding a category.  I want it to not exit until I click the logout button.

what can i do to fix this problem?

DashboardAdmin Activity

```
public class DashboardAdminActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private ActivityDashboardAdminBinding binding;

    //firebase auth
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding=ActivityDashboardAdminBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        //init firebase auth
        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        checkUser();

        binding.logoutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                firebaseAuth.signOut();
                checkUser();
            }
        });

        //handle click, start category add screen
        binding.addCategoryBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(DashboardAdminActivity.this,CategoryAddActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private void checkUser() {
        //get current user
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser == null){
            //not logged in go to main screen
            startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
        else{
            //logged in get user info
            String email= firebaseUser.getEmail();
            //set in textview of toolbar
            binding.subtitleTv.setText(email);
        }
    }
```

CategoryAddActivity

```
public class CategoryAddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityCategoryAddBinding binding;

    //firebase auth
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    //progress dialog
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding=ActivityCategoryAddBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        //init firebase auth
        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //configure progress dialog
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("please wait!");
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        //handle click go back
        binding.backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        //handle click begin upload category
        binding.submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                validateData();
            }
        });
    }

    private String category="";
    private void validateData() {
        /*Before adding validate data*/

        //get data
        category=binding.categoryEt.getText().toString().trim();
        //validate if not empty
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(category)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "please wriete a category name..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            addCategoryFirebase();
        }
    }

    private void addCategoryFirebase() {
        //show progress
        progressDialog.setMessage("category adding..");
        progressDialog.show();

        //get timestamp
        Long timestamp=System.currentTimeMillis();
        //setup info to add in firebase db
        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap=new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("id",""+timestamp);
        hashMap.put("category",""+category);
        hashMap.put("timestamp",timestamp);
        hashMap.put("uid",""+firebaseAuth.getUid());


        //set data to db
        DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Categories");
        ref.child(""+timestamp)
                .setValue(hashMap)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                        //data added to db
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(CategoryAddActivity.this, "category added succesfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        //data not added to db
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(CategoryAddActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: here is the problem: after logging in, there is no problem navigating through activities.  but when I press the back button on the Add category page, it exits my account and redirects it to the login page again.  normally it should have taken me to the admin page without logging out of my account.  I have to re-login every time I press the back button after adding a category.  I want it to not exit until I click the logout button.

Comment: Is your app crashing?

Comment: yes sometimes is crashing sometimes is logout.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: ScreenDecorations
                                                                                                    Process: com.android.systemui, PID: 2430
                                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter bottomLeft

Comment: Which is the exact line of code that produces the NullPointerException?

Comment: I didnt understand what did you mean? Can you explain in a few more words?